# Can I use spaces for List Item titles?

Tags: item

Within SharePoint 2013 can I use spaces for the Item titles?

Comment: Do u mean to say List Column Name ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use spaces in titles, however this leads to there being `%20`s in your URLs. A good practice is when provisioning the list, to create the title without spaces, then edit the title to include the spaces upon completion. This will set the internal URL without spaces and give you a pretty display.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use spaces in item titles.